# Creating a Spring 4 MVC project with annotations and no xml files

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I'm new to Spring MVC and Hibernate. I'm trying to start a project by following tutorials but I have been running into problems as my project structure is not consistent with the tutorials I am reading.

I have downloaded the latest STS and I do see the option of creating an Spring MVC project. However it is based on Spring 3 and still uses XML files. From what I have read it looks like there is a way to do it without XML files since Spring 3. I prefer annotations over XML files greatly.

How can I create a Spring MVC 4 application that is based on annotations and relies on xml files minimally?

EDIT:
I want to create a web project

Comment: are you trying to start a web project, or desktop application?

Comment: I want a web project

Comment: Have you seen the spring.io guides? https://spring.io/guides

Answer (score 2):

Here is a squeletal example of full java configuration. You will need :

- a class extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` to replace the old `web.xml` file
- one or more `@Configuration` annotaded class(es) to initialize the root context (replaces the old `applicationContext.xml`)
- one or more `@Configuration` annotaded class(es) to initialize the `DispatcherServlet` context (replaces the old `dispatcher-servlet.xml`)

This is the *`web.xml`* :

```
public class WebAppConf extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // declare root context configuration classes
        return new Class<?>[]{ RootConf.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // declare servlet context configuration classes
        return new Class<?>[]{ ServletConf.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // mapping of DispatcherServlet
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
        // additional configuration, here for MultipartConfig
        super.customizeRegistration(registration);
        MultipartConfigElement multipartConf = new MultipartConfigElement("", 200000L, -1L, 0);
        registration.setMultipartConfig(multipartConf);
    }
}
```

`RootConf` will declare business model, service and dao beans and is not shown here.

`ServletConf` declares the controllers and servlet configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
// declare where to find annotated controllers
@ComponentScan({"org.example.web"})
public class ServletConf extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
    @Bean
    ViewResolver internalViewResolver() {
        // the view resolver bean ...
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

As said above, it is squeletal, but it comes from a working minimal example so you should be able to start with that and extend it at will. In my example, the above three classes live in a `org.example.config` package that will never be scanned for autodetecting other configuration classes or annotated beans.

Hope it helps ...

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your question fully, but hopefully the links will be useful.

[WebApplicationInitializer - A 100% code based approach to configuration](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)

as well as [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html)

Also, if you have the time, reading the relevant sections of [Spring's MVC chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) of their documentation is helpful.

Comment: It looks like there isn't much documentation on the code based implementation of Spring. Do you think it would be better for a newb like me to start with the XML based?

Comment: There is definitely way more resources for spring + xml, but you can find some good resources on code based approach as well.  Here is a link to a tutorial that guides you from a HelloWorld to a database driven application using no xml: http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/your-next-java-web-app-less-xml-no-long-restarts-fewer-hassles-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

I Wish that this link will be helpful for you [Spring security with annotation Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/)

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of STS integrate the Spring guides from https://spring.io/guides directly, try the "Import Spring Getting Started Content" wizard. There are good guides included for creating a Spring Boot based web service, for example, among many others.