# class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist using java config

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4.0.2, eclipse `JEE marse`, `Tomcat v7.0`. I have to test an example from [here](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/). My project structure is:

```
Java Resources 
    src
        com.test.config 
            HelloConfig.java
            HelloController.java
            HelloInitializer.java
WebContent
    META-INF
        MANIFEST.MF
    WEB-INF
        lib
        view
            welcome.jsp
```

Content of my `HelloConfig.java` is:

```
package com.test.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.config")
public class HelloConfig {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new  InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

And content of my `HelloInitializer.java`:

```
package com.test.config;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class HelloInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(HelloConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/hello/*");
    }
}
```

And content of my `HelloController.java`:

```
package com.test.config;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World from Spring 4 MVC");
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloagain", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHelloAgain(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World Again, from Spring 4 MVC");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

But I ran this project on the server and got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
... 21 more

Jul 27, 2016 10:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 27, 2016 10:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/HelloMVC] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 27, 2016 10:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 27, 2016 10:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5719)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have used this code instead of last `HelloInitializer.java`:

```
package com.test.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class HelloInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HelloConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HelloMVC]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HelloMVC]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: getServletConfigClasses() did not return any configuration classes
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.createServletApplicationContext(AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.registerDispatcherServlet(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5513)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Jul 27, 2016 11:30:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Jul 27, 2016 11:30:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: create a file named `applicationContext.xml` in src/main/resources

Comment: what is content of this file?

Comment: Google about applicationcontext

Comment: when i am using java to config the web app i must use xml to config too? can i fix it using java?

Comment: No but Looks like you have a link to the XML file, or you have not configured your app right

Comment: @hamid you can get help here http://javabeat.net/spring-mvc-application-context/

Comment: @Imran thanks for time but i want to config web app just using java. can you help me to do it?

Comment: Let `getRootConfigClasses` return `null` and `getServletConfigClasses` return your `HelloConfig` class. The context for the `ContextLoaderListener`  can be `null` it cannot be for the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: @M.Deinum i have test it but got this error: can not parse applicationContext.xml may not exists

Comment: @hamid Use this link for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519426/creating-a-spring-4-mvc-project-with-annotations-and-no-xml-files

Comment: Not if you use the second `HelloInitializer` that extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. In the case of `null` it will not create a `ContextLoaderListener`. also make sure you don't have an accidental `web.xml` hanging around!

Comment: @M.Deinum i update question in this way but i got same errors. and i do not have web.xml in this project

Comment: Your code doesn't represent the exception... With that code you cannot get the exception you have. Also if you get the **same exception** your code isn't compiled and deployed to your container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your frontcontroller, known as Dispatcherservlet is not able to locate your Config class . **try this**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
public class HelloConfig { }
```

or

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.*")
public class HelloConfig { }
```

instead of this

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.config")
public class HelloConfig {}
```

Comment: If your app is not private, could you upload your it on github ,dropbox, googledrive or whatever and share the link. ?

Answer (score 1):

you have share your folder structure as this:

```
Java Resources 
    src
        com.test.config 
            HelloConfig.java
            HelloController.java
            HelloInitializer.java
WebContent
    META-INF
        MANIFEST.MF
    WEB-INF
        lib
        view
            welcome.jsp
```

I couldn't find your HelloConfig-servlet.xml inside WEB_INF here. If you really have that inside WEB-INF but somehow miss it in here, I would suggest you to check your buildpath confiuration. My guess is somehow WEB-INF is not registered in the build path

Comment: i update question and i deleted @ImportResource( ... ) .
but i got same error.

Comment: Innstead of using WebApplicationInitializer use AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and register your config class with this. AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer is much more sophisticated.

Comment: i updated question. i have tested AbstractAnnotationConfigDespatcherServletInitializer but i got new errors can you help me how to user this class.

Comment: Dont try WebApplicationInitializer with AbstractAnnotationConfigDespatcherServletInitializer. Use only AbstractAnnotationConfigDespatcherServletInitializer.It will definitely solve your problem

Comment: thanks for time. i have tested both of them one by one not together but i got same error.

Comment: can you please provide full excaption details when using AbstractAnnotationConfigDespatcherServletInitializer?